# Entity Framework One-to-one or zero - Database first

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm trying to create a setup where I have different entities (e.g. User and Customer). Each of these entities have some Login-information which I store in a Login-table to avoid having to do duplicate work on the different entities requiring Login-data.

However - I can't get the setup to work using Entity Framework. I hope you can help me out :)

My database has 3 tables:

**Users**

- Id (PK)
- Name
- ...
- Login_Id (FK to Login.Id)

**Customers**

- Id (PK)
- CustomerNumber
- ...
- Login_Id (FK to Login.Id)

**Logins**

- Id (PK)
- Username
- Password

...

Each entity has one - and only one - login. So a given User has one Login. And a given Customer has one Login.

I need to be able to do something like this in C#:

```
var user = _userService.GetUser(2);
user.Login.Username;

var customer = _customerService.GetCustomer("abc");
customer.Login.Username;
```

But I simply cannot get the EF mappings to work.

I've tried changing my database schema so that Logins contains nullable User_Id and Customer_Id columns - but the result is the same. My Login-entity is null when accessing User or Customer. And I've already added the

```
Include(i => i.Login);
```

I might have just gone totally blind looking at it. I've read dusins of posts about this - but the majority of them seems to focus on Code-First and not Db-First (e.g. http://blog.bennymichielsen.be/2011/06/02/entity-framework-4-1-one-to-one-mapping/)

Could someone please supply me with the EF Fluent API mappings to get this to work?

Thank you guys so much! :)

Comment: Code-First still works if the DB already exists.

Comment: Agreed. However I simply cannot get this working :/

Comment: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve